# GCP Data Catalog - ONE for all projects (of one and more orgs)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, organization, project-organization, google-data-catalog

What is the best practice

- to get a company wide (one or more organisations each with multiple folders and projects)
- INTO one central and all metadata contained data catalog ?

(if "multiple orgs" is too complex than let's start with one)

Comment: Not possible  for now. You can open an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: "Offers a unified view of all datasets". Google is promising it (and sells it this way), right? Why is nowhere written that in Google Cloud you get [Cloud] Data Silos [with API], that's what projects currently are, right?

Comment: To what extent would it currently be possible?

Comment: I reached my Google contacts. I will let you know when I have an answer.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks, I opened an issue as well

Comment: Seems like this is already being addressed in the created Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/172933220

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a sample showing how to work with one organization.

The main ideia is to use a Tag Central Project, where you store the common resources, like Tag Templates, Policy Tags and Custom Entries that could be reused.

So you have:

- Tag Central Project
- List of Analytics Projects (Where you have the data assets)

Then the next thing is the user personas you would use, I'd suggest starting with:

- Data Governors
- Data Curators
- Data Analysts

This [google-datacatalog-governance-best-pratices](https://github.com/mesmacosta/google-datacatalog-governance-best-pratices) GitHub repo contains the code which uses terraform to automatically set up those governance best practices I mentioned.

You can adapt those samples to work at folder or organization level by changing the terraform resources.